# Why does the inequality $1-x^5 \leq 5(1-x)$ hold? If $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

It is obviously true, by analyzing the plot of these two functions. But how can one prove it analytically?

Comment: Can you use calculus to find extrema of the difference?

Answer (score 5):

For $x\in[0,1]$ we have $0\leq x^n\leq 1$, $n\in\mathbb N$. Then we simply get that

$$
\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}=\frac{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4\leq 5.
$$

Multiplying by $1-x$ we show that the given relation holds true.

Comment: Minor quibble: $(1-x^5)/(1-x)$ is not defined for $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

For example, you can take $f(x) = 5(1-x)+x^5-1$ and observe that $f'(x) = -5 + 5x^4 = 5(1-x^4)$ and so observe that $x=1$ is a turning point and since no $x \in (0,1)$ is a turning point, then $\max_{[0,1]} f$ is $f(0)$ or $f(1)$. Evidently, the function is decreasing on that interval thus implying that the maximum is $f(0)$ and the minimum is $f(1)=0$. Therefore, $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. In other words,

$$  5(1-x)+x^5-1 \geq 0 $$

which is certainly equivalent to

$$ \boxed{5(1-x) \geq 1 - x^5 } $$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach without calculus: The given inequality can be (through factoring) transformed into $(x-1)^2(x^3+2x^2+3x+4) \geq 0$ Since $(x-1)^2$ never gets negative and the coefficients of the cubic are all positive, you can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

By the Bernoulli inequality,
$$
x^5=(1-(1-x))^5\ge 1-5(1-x)
$$
as long as $-(1-x)\ge -1\iff x\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$1-x^5 = (1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3 + x^4)$

And $1+x + x^2+x^3 + x^4 \le 1 + 1 + 1+ 1+ 1=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^5.$ For $x\in [0,1],$ the MVT shows there exists  $c_x\in (x,1)$ such that

$$f(1)-f(x) = f'(c_x)(1-x) = 5c_x^{\,4}(1-x) \le 5 (1-x).$$

Answer (score -1):

Replacing $x$ by $1+y$ gives
$$ (1+y)^5 - 5y - 1 = y^5 + 5y^4 + 10y^3 + 10y^2 > 0 $$
when $y>0$, i.e. when $x>-1$, so $x^5 + 5(1-x) - 1 > 0$, equivalent to your inequality. The same works if $5$ is replaced any positive integer.